# In the given figure, two squares A and B (of areas 'a sq. units and 'b' sq. units respectively) lie inside a bigger square of side 12 units. Find a+b.

Tags: geometry

According to the question: There are 2 squares $A$ and $B$ which have an area of $a$ sq. units and $b$ sq. units respectively. They all lie inside a square of side 12 cm. I have to find $a+b$

Here is a sample image.

[image]

What I have tried so far:
$
side=12;  
area=side^2=12^2=144 sq. units
$

Since there is a diagonal in the square, it divides the square into 2 equal halves with area $72 sq. units$

Then, I assumed that the vertex of the square bisects the diagonal of the main square. And, I got the answer $b=36$

I don't know how to get the area of $a$. I am even not sure that my area for $b$ is correct. So, how can I find the area for $a$ ($b$ if my area for $b$ is wrong)?

If I have missed something obvious, please be gentle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The area of $B$ is indeed $36$ -- you can see that the two triangles in the lower half along with $B$ have total area equal to that of $B$, so $B$ must have HALF the area of the lower triangle, i.e., $72/2 = 36 = b$.

For the upper triangle, you might try to work out how long the side $a$ of square $A$ is. The total length of the long horizontal line in the figure is $12 \sqrt{2}$, by Pythagoras. It sure looks to me as if the side of $A$ is one third of that, i.e., $4 \sqrt{2}$. So the area
of $A$ is $32$.

Comment: The two big triangles in the upper triangle are each half the area of square A, and the small triangle is a quarter the area.

Comment: Agreed. If we measure in units of 1/4-square, there are four of those INSIDE and five outside, so the area is $4/9$ of $72$, which is $32$.

Comment: Can you please explain how can we be sure that side of A is one-third of the diagonal

Comment: @RobertIsrael, can you please the logic behind triangles equal to half of bigger triangle area? Thanks

Comment: Bisect one of the bigger triangles and see that half of it is congruent to the small triangle.